# Activity indicator not always rendered

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiactivityindicatorview

I have code that triggers an activity indicator:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

Once it is triggered I continue to launch some background tasks (e.g. go to server, fetch data, callback when done).

The problem I have is that the behaviour of the activity indicator is inconsistent in the sense that from displaying on UI it sometimes visible/gets rendered and animating and sometimes does not (especially if the app was in the background and returned to foreground)

I am not sure what I need to do to ensure that it consistently rendered on the screen when I call `startAnimating()` before I proceed to launch background tasks.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you may work with UI outside main thread. Try wrap code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your code to run on the main queue/thread
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
});
```

Comment: Problem solved! I did not realise that even though I was expecting 'execution in order' I had to `dispatch_async`.